# Where is Hydro Medusa?

Tags: ros, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Does anyone have an idea of when the next distro H will be released exactly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63519/where-is-hydro-medusa?/) by [amine23](https://answers.ros.org/users/3879/amine23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2013-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the ros-users mailing list [an announcment](https://code.ros.org/lurker/attach/3@20130518.003149.51355585.attach) was made that the Hydro release will be delayed due to the results of a [survey](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzNmzxy4pVGMZHd2b1BSWVlHVHM/edit) asking how users would like to see the ROS release cycle scheduled. <strike>At this time I have not heard of any new release date scheduled for Hydro.</strike>

An [updated timeline](https://code.ros.org/lurker/thread/20130531.215149.0e92fc60.en.html) for the Hydro release has been proposed on the ros-users mailing list.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2013-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4949/bernhard/) on 2013-06-27**:
As of now the last suggested release date was the 29th July, beta freeze 29th june. I think the date is believable, but not set in stone yet.